# Running SQL in Python with Escaped Characters

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to run the following code in SQL (Snowflake) from Python.

```
"WHERE SOMECOLUMN  LIKE 'product\\\\_%\\\\_season\\\\_s%\\\\_premium' ESCAPE '\\\\'"
```

For the avoidance of doubt each backslash in the SQL is repeated twice.

When I run this through Python I get the error

```
001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 358 unexpected '_'.
```

How can I properly escape this string?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I needed to escape the % with %% and the \\ with \\\\

Answer (score 1):

[ESCAPE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/like.html) string could be any character, so using different character is easier and more readable, for instance `~`:

> escape
>
> Character(s) inserted in front of a wildcard character to indicate that the wildcard should be interpreted as a regular character and not as a wildcard.

```
"WHERE SOMECOLUMN  LIKE 'product~_%~_season~_s%~_premium' ESCAPE '~'"
```